# Weird sound when doing something forbidden

Tags: macos, keyboard, audio, hardware

MBP Mid 2012 on OSX 10.10.5

Since a couple of months I recogniz a weird sound on my computer. It appears whenever I do something "forbidden", i.e. using a key in a programm which has no functionality.

You can listen to the sound [here](http://sendvid.com/o6e4fjg1). I "made" it through opening Quicktime with a video, stopping the video and repeatedly pushing the button "d" on my keyboard.
Any ideas? Is that the "your doing somthing 'forbidden' sound" which I did not recognize before?

Comment: What is the affected soft ?

Comment: @MrMojoRisin whenever I do something "forbidden" in any program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize this sound in your System Preferences Sound settings

[image]

Comment: haha thats supposed to sound like a frog?! thanks!